# Cross_validate from sklearn return all Nan (TimeSeriesSplit)

Tags: cross-validation

I've encountered several questions asking why cros_val_score returns all 'nan'. Mine is slightly different. If I run:

```
cross_validate( Lasso(alpha=0.1,) , X.values, y.values, cv = n_splits, )
```

I correctly get a the array 'test_score' of scores ('fit_time' and 'score_time' are fine in both examples). I can't understand why as soon as I change to:

```
cross_validate( Lasso(alpha=alpha,) , X.values, y.values, cv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=n_splits , test_size = 1 ), )
```

I get all 'nan'. As long as I understand from documentation, the score returned must be one for each fold, no matter how did you build them.. So what's wrong?

PS: X and Y are two dataframe, X-> (Nsamples,Nfeatures) and y-> (Nsamples, Ntargets)